# How do I retrieve the token using python

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to send post and get requests to this [website](http://maps.address.gov.sa/Home/Index?lang=en). However all the requests I have observed in chrome tools use a token parameter which the website generates at the beginning of launching the website. Is there anyway I can generate this token using python libraries like requests?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is yes and no.
There is a way with which these tokens are generated so they can generate the tokens.
But one of the reason they are using these tokens to avoid web-scraping.
so even you discover now and they detect the traffic. they can change the token generation in future. so It is not straight forward.

Still you want to pursue this path some leads:

1. collect tokens with time-stamp and other params. bigger the data better it is to analyze.
2. brute-force the token generation and try this will lead to DDoS so careful with this approach.
3. use selenium for this task.

Be careful with doing web scraping as it may not be legal. I am no lawyer. but it may have bad repercussions. I am providing this info just to be used at your own risk.